# Required fields in form doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, subscription

I am trying to make a subscription form with only input as email-id.
First, I made using html and php wherein it stored the email-id and also it was checking for required parameters like **'@'**  and '.' etc.

**Like email-id ="d" showed error**

But once i added the ajax, it took care about if email-id exist in the table than showed already subscribed but the feature about require parameter stopped working.

**Like email-id= "d" also worked**

Code is as follows :

**index.html**

```
<form  class="searchform" method ="post" >
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required="required" />
        <button id="submit" type="submit"> </button>
</form>
```

Ajax file : **script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){

var email = $("#email").val();

var dataString =  '&email='+ email ;
if(email=='')
{
alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "email.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
alert(result);
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

Php database code : **email.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$dbname= "mydbname";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password,$dbname);
if(! $dbhandle )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$email=$_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO  email_table". "(email)". "VALUES ('$email')";

if (mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sql)) {
    echo "You have subscribed successfully";
} else {
    echo "You have already been subscribed";
}
?>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use: http://jqueryvalidation.org

Comment: You should look up `SQL injection` on Google and check your server side code too (you are at risk...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery/JS does not know anything about the HTML form validation. Therefore you'll need to validate it with jQuery/JS like:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    if($("form")[0].checkValidity()) {
        //your form execution code
    }else console.log("invalid form");
});
```

[HTML5 validation before ajax submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713491/html5-validation-before-ajax-submit)

You could also handle the response from a PHP file using AJAX to check if it was empty.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $(".class").html(response);
        }
    });
```

the PHP file could be:

```
if ($_POST['email'] == "") {
   echo 'Please enter an email';
}
```

"Please enter an email" would be the error response and it would be placed inside whatever has the class='class'

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `required="required"`, just `required` inside of your `<input>` tag.